# Space between spaces doesn't work on iOS

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am making signature for outlook. In browser it looks good also in outlook, gmail and couple other local mails.

on Android it works also good but when I am sending email on my iPhone this blue line ( at the left ) is stripped because spaces doesn't work. It also occurs on one email.

I've created example to show that everything looks good here.

```html
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" display:block; width:100%;>
    <table style="
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="5" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px; border-left:solid 10px #3580C2;"></th>
            <th>
                <div style="text-align:left; font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14px; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; color: #000; text-align:left;">Test</span><br><br>
                    <span style="font-size: 19px; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; color: #3580C2; text-align:left;">Name</span><br>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; color: #000; text-align:left;">Test Test</span>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="test/image001.png" width="139" height="209" alt="zdjecie" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle; line-height: 1.5em;">
                <div style="font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <img alt="phone" src="test/image006.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline;" ></img>
                    <span style="font-size: 15; display: inline; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp 000 000 000</span>
                    <br>
                    <img alt="fax" src="test/image008.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline;">
                    </img>
                    <span style="font-size: 15; display: inline; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp 000 000 000</span>
                    <br>
                    <img alt="cell" src="test/image010.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline;">
                    </img>
                    <span style="font-size: 15; display: inline; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp 000 000 000</span>
                    <br>
                    <img alt="mail" src="test/image012.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; "></img>
                    <span style="font-size: 15; display: inline">&nbsp name@web.com</span>
                    <br><br>
                    <span style="display: inline; font-size: 16"><b>Company</b></span>
                    <br>
                    <span style="display: inline; font-size: 15">Address</span>
                    <br>
                    <span style="display: inline; font-size: 15">NIP: 00000000</span>
                    <br>
                    <a style="color:black; text-decoration:none; display: block;" href="http://www.web.com">
                        <span style="display: inline; font-size: 16;"><b>www.web.com</b></span></a>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<table style="
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 0px 0px 0 15px; border-left:solid 10px #3580C2; margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0; text-align:left; line-height: 18px;"></th>

    <td rowspan="2">
    <br>
<img src="test/image014.png" style="width: 274px; height: 35px;"></img>
<br><br>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: -10px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0;
    display: block;">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 0px 0px 0 15px; border-left:solid 10px #3580C2; margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0; text-align:left; line-height: 18px;"></th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td style="width: 760px;">
     <div style="font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#aaa; margin-left: 15px;">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam suscipit justo eros. Vivamus dictum tempus venenatis. Donec at tincidunt quam.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam suscipit justo eros. Vivamus dictum tempus venenatis. Donec at tincidunt quam. Phasellus sodales elementum nisl ornare ultricies. Sed leo ex, congue sed gravida eu, accumsan vel dui. Vivamus dolor mi, pharetra non augue ut, eleifend porta ipsum. Ut laoreet pellentesque sem ac imperdiet. Nulla nec enim metus. Nam interdum, nisl at pharetra venenatis, dolor odio efficitur neque, eget tincidunt purus erat sed velit. Curabitur dictum, augue vel auctor bibendum, quam nisl malesuada leo, eu gravida est turpis at justo. Nullam quis urna a eros accumsan tristique dictum eget massa. Vivamus fermentum ante metus, maximus eleifend dui ultricies ut. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque ut vehicula augue. Ut interdum efficitur eros, porta mollis odio semper quis..</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam suscipit justo eros. Vivamus dictum tempus venenatis. Donec at tincidunt quam. Phasellus sodales elementum nisl ornare ultricies. Sed leo ex, congue sed gravida eu, accumsan vel dui. Vivamus dolor mi, pharetra non augue ut, eleifend porta ipsum. Ut laoreet pellentesque sem ac imperdiet. Nulla nec enim metus. Nam interdum, nisl at pharetra venenatis, dolor odio efficitur neque, eget tincidunt purus erat sed velit. Curabitur dictum, augue vel auctor bibendum, quam nisl malesuada leo, eu gravida est turpis at justo. Nullam quis urna a eros accumsan tristique dictum eget massa. Vivamus fermentum ante metus, maximus eleifend dui ultricies ut. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque ut vehicula augue. Ut interdum efficitur eros, porta mollis odio semper quis.</p>
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

And this is what happend with blue line. It looks like three tables with big space between.
[Stripped line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVFAi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no answere for your question itself but wouldnt it be easier to simply just put a div over the whole table and use the following css:

```
.divclass {
     border-left-width:10px;
     border-left-style:solid;
     border-left-color:#3580C2;
}
```

I think that would have been easier at all and maybe it helps for ur IOS problem too? Comment if it might solve your problem :)

EDIT: I forgot if you make a div over the table you might need float:left..

```
.divclass {
     border-left-width:10px;
     border-left-style:solid;
     border-left-color:#3580C2;
     float:left;
}
```